# boundary conditions for liquid with surface tension

Tags: surface-tension, navier-stokes

so one uses equations of motion to describe liquids (e.g. Navier–Stokes equations). These are equations for $\vec{v}(\vec{r},t)$ with boundary conditions on the surface $S$ of the liquid (e.g. $\vec{v}(\vec{r}\in S,t) = \vec{0}$).

How should one incorporate surface tension $\sigma$ in these equations/boundary conditions? It seems, only boundary conditions must change, and $\Delta p = \sigma (1/R_1 + 1/R_2)$ is the first thing that comes to mind, but how to get $1/R$ from $\vec{v}(\vec{r},t)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want $1/R$ (although technically it means the same) but rather the full curvature term: $\Delta p=\sigma \kappa$. In fact you will get a source term in the Navier-Stokes equations that looks like this:
$$\sigma \kappa \delta(n) \mathbf{n} $$
where $\delta(n)$ is the [Dirac Delta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeltaFunction.html) that only has a value at the interface and $\mathbf{n}$ is the interface normal. The curvature $\kappa$ can be written as the divergence of the unit interface normal: $$\kappa=\nabla \cdot \mathbf{\frac{n}{|n|}} $$

Apart from the source term you indeed also have boundary conditions on the interface which are basically the standard free slip condition and a jump for the normal stress coming again from the Laplace pressure. There is a good explanation of these in the first part of the seminal work on fluid-fluid CFD by [Brackbill](http://www.ann.jussieu.fr/~frey/papers/Navier-Stokes/Brackbill%20J.U.,%20A%20continuum%20method%20for%20modeling%20surface%20tension.pdf).

If you are interested in the curvature itself, I think [Slides 22-28 of this course](http://www.utwente.nl/tnw/pcf/education/jmbc_course_on_capillarity_driv/Presentations/wetting_basics.pdf) on wetting are probably also a good source to take a look at for more background.